# What are the exact model of those two chips?

Tags: integrated-circuit

[image]

I have my laptop acer nitro 5. But i did something wrong and the usb power voltage became 0V.

Then i realized that those two chips has broken. So i tried to search the two chip's name which was written on top of the chip but no results came.

The letter written on the first chip is k2j08
And second chip is JCV

Can anyone help me to find the exact model of those chips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is a lot of "fluff" going on in the news this weekend in the US by our "modern news sources" (that always appear to be reporting the same things read from the same cheat-sheet, but using different software algorithms to get people to click on them and little if any background or research to rub between them) about Biden and local repair stores and DIY repair (someday), I think it's still a long way off if ever in the US. In the meantime, manufacturers (and Samsung, in particular) are often hide-bound before they will tell you the COTS parts you might buy to replace these (assuming they may be available to you, at all.)

That said, there are a few ways left to us. And given some of the details you've provided the best I can come up with are these thoughts:

- **K2J08**: This is probably some kind of step-up DC/DC converter. A list of these can be found [here](http://www.aeneas.com.tw/search/search_advanced/ricoh/BOOST_DCDC/RP400xxx1B/ME-RP400xxx1B-SOT-23-5.pdf) and on this page you can see that the part #*RP400N261B* is labeled as a K2J, which matches your first three characters on the package. This is a SOT-23-5 packaged device that outputs (I think) \$2.6\:\text{V}\$ from Ricoh. I found a datasheet [here](https://www.datasheets.com/en/part-details/rp400n261b-tr-fe-ricoh-electronic-devices-co---ltd-42800974#datasheet), though I don't use that site for much. Use it at your own risk.
- **JCV**: Your image appears to show a SOT-23-6 package for this, but the closest I I think I can find is an [S-80136ANMC-JCVT2G](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ABLIC/S-80136ANMC-JCVT2G?qs=T4pMzK1X4f5B3l4c6jodQg%3D%3D). The datasheet is at [this Mouser page](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/360/S801_E-1606001.pdf). That's a SOT-23-5, which worries me a bit. But this is the best I could do in helping out.

The above may give you something to go on, anyway. You should look over the pinouts and compare with what you see on the board to see if things make sense -- or if the board's parts and layout conflict with the ideas above.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering to my question! I can now finally fix it.